# Mongoose save modified users array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this `Users` array here which I modified and now I want to save it. But it won't let me save because I get an error: `save is not a function`. How can I solve this ?

Code:

```
let users = await User.find({served: false});

users.splice(userIndex, 1);

userIndex++;

users.splice(userIndex, 0, user);
users.save() // save is not a function
```

**UPDATE**

```
User.insertMany(users).then(docs => {
    console.log(docs)
})
```

This would save it but I get duplication error of documents. Maybe I could wipe out all unserved users and add these new ones ?

Comment: changes users.save() to User.save(users)

Comment: Still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

This worked. I removed the elements then added them again modified.

```
User.deleteMany({served: false}).then(() => {
    User.insertMany(users).then(users => {
        console.log(users)
    })
});
```